# Using dynamic URL to link to Drillthrough pages within the same report in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dynamic-url, drillthrough

I have a report in Power BI. Currently I can drill through from home page using Field A to multiple other pages (say page for Category 1, page for Category 2, page for Category 3, etc.).

Is there a way to use dynamic parameters in a URL to replicate the effect of Drill through functionality? 
(So that I can determine a specific value of Field A, using some calculation I have, and pass it through as a parameter)

When I checked, the URL for a Category X page didn't change based on the value of Field A I selected to Drill through.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can create dynamic text measures to use for URLs.

Here are a couple of more detailed resources:

https://www.kasperonbi.com/creating-a-hyperlink-with-filters-through-dax/

https://www.cloudfronts.com/dynamic-url-filtering-power-bi/

Comment: Thank you!
I guess my question is also around filtering vs drill through functionality, as it seems to work slightly differently. I can see how I can dynamically filter a page, which contains all possible values to begin with. But I am not sure about a drill through page, which only works once you actively drill through.